# How to calculate average of an array for only entered values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to calculate the average of an array for only the values that aren't 0. My array is of size 15, because it could have up to 15 values in it.

When I calculate the average, it uses all 15 values, even though 12 of them are 0 at the start. How do I prevent 0.0’s from being considered?

```
for(double element: majorA) {
       Sum += element;
}
average = sum / majorA.length;
System.out.printf("%.5f\n", average);
```

The array also isn't a defined set, but dependent on what the user inputs. The initial array is:

```
double[] majorA = new double[15];
```

Then gets values as need:

```
majorA[0] = num1;
majorA[1] = num2;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add a counter that keeps track and use that instead of the array length.

```
int count = 0;
for(double element: majorA) {
   if(element > 0.0) {
       Sum += element;
       count += 1;
   }
}
average = sum / count;
System.out.printf("%.5f\n", average);
```

Comment: Thanks. Probably should have thought of that myself. I was trying to see if i could do something to the array specifically. Forgot I could just count if its not 0

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with

```
Arrays.stream(majorA).filter(d -> d != 0).average().orElse(0)
```

this will filter out all values that are 0s and will calculate the average. Even if there is nothing left in the array will display 0 because of `.orElse(0)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a counter in the loop that increments only if the number !=0

```
int count = 0;
for(double element: majorA) {
   if(element != 0.0){
       sum += element;
       count++;
   }
}
average = (count == 0) ? 0 : sum / count;
```

Comment: `element` has a `double` type. That means we can not compare it with integer value `0`. I think more safely use Double.compare() method. Also, we should check `if (count != 0)` for avoiding dividing by zero in `sum / count` statement.